# Save two imageview at one

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, save

I would like to overlay two imageview in order to obtain a single photo to save. The first imageview is preloaded in the application while the latter choose from the gallery of the phone. Before you save the new image I would like to write to them. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: you can do with Layer-List http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Comment: But how can I write on the photo?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html

Answer (score 0):

//Use LayerDrawable 
it will Create a new layer drawable with the list of specified layers.

```
        Drawable item0 = drawable1;
        Drawable item1 = drawable2;
        LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{item0, item1});
```

check [this Link](http://jacekdalkowski.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/android-draw-a-number-of-bitmaps-or-drawables-into-a-single-drawable/)

Comment: is there an example to better understand how to do?